# Is there a synonym for "fan meeting"?

Tags: single-word-requests

During my project I have many new friends and followers in a city, and I am about to go there. I want to meet them in a group talk. I think the correct word for it is "fan meeting", but I feel quite ashamed for using that word, as it sounds like I'm arrogant. Is there a more neutral way to describe that? I don't think "follower meeting" is natural, and people can see through it that it's just another way to use "fan meeting".

Comment: There must be content you are planning besides patting each other's backs. Focus on that instead of a synonym for fan meeting, which will be ... a fan meeting. Will you present a *project update*?

Comment: @YosefBaskin yes, in that meeting surely people will ask about the project, for example the motivation I commit to this project, the outcome, my future life, etc. But I imagine this is an informal talk, when I also ask about their life and the like, rather than a presentation with slideshows and chart and data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just called **a meetup**.

You'll be organizing it, and they know who you are.

If you need an event title, call it, for example: **@Ooker Austin Meetup**

Per your comment, if you want to suggest that this is a big event, try **@Ooker 2021 Austin Meetup**

Comment: ohh I realize Austin is a name of place, not a person name

Comment: Perhaps I should have used *@Ooker San Francisco  Meetup* as an example...

Answer (score 0):

Given the context, I think that whatever term you use instead of 'fan' would ultimately imply the same thing. Would you consider using 'supporter' instead of 'fan'? You can say 'Supporters' Group Meeting'.